# Water level changes after scrap iron thrown off a barge

Tags: fluid-statics

I'm currently trying to work through Physics by HRK, Edition 5. I've come across this problem in the Fluid Statics section which I, being an amateur, decided to google. The exercise reads:

> A barge filled with scrap iron is in a canal lock. If the iron is thrown overboard, what happens to the water level in the lock? What if it is thrown onto the land beside the canal?

Mixed results so far from:

https://www.askiitians.com/forums/Mechanics/a-barge-filled-with-scrap-iron-is-in-a-canal-lock_122702.htm
https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20080316062239AAVmZxk
[http://cosweb1.fau.edu/~jordanrg/busters_9/answers_9.htm#Ex_7](http://cosweb1.fau.edu/%7Ejordanrg/busters_9/answers_9.htm#Ex_7)

Also, if anyone knows where I can find solutions to ALL the questions and exercises of HRK, I'd really appreciate it!

Comment: Do you know Archimedes principle?

Comment: Yes, isn't it the buoyant force on a submerged equals the weight of the volume displaced by the submerged object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While the iron is on the barge, the barge and all it's load is buoyant. It is displacing all of it's weight in water, so the water level is high. When the iron is thrown into the water the barge and it's remaining load weighs less so it rises some, displacing less water. The iron thrown in the water sinks, it weighs more than the water that it's volume displaces. Now not all of the total of the barge and it's original load is displacing it's weight in water, as some of the iron's weight is resting against the bottom of the canal. Since less water is now displaced it's level will go down. When the iron is unloaded onto the land, even less water is displaced by the unloaded barge's weight. Then the water level will be even lower.

Comment: The word "its" is misspelled 7 times.  It's very distracting.

Comment: Apologies, I will edit.. It has been a long day.